# Rails 4 includes eager loading not saving me a single database call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

According to the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), paragraph 13.1.1, eager loading should be done like this

```
Post.includes(:category, :comments)
```

which is exactly what I'm doing (even deep eager loading)

```
@text = Text.includes({usuario: :profile }, :comments, :tags, :likes, :dislikes, :text_medals).where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

but I see the server log:

```
  Texto Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE "textos"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "19"]]
  Texto Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE "textos"."id" = 19 ORDER BY "textos"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Usuario Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" WHERE "usuarios"."id" IN (12)
  Profile Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."usuario_id" IN (12)
  Comment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Texto' AND "comments"."commentable_id" IN (19)
  SQL (1.1ms)  SELECT "tags".*, "t0"."texto_id" AS ar_association_key_name FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "tags_textos" "t0" ON "tags"."id" = "t0"."tag_id" WHERE "t0"."texto_id" IN (19)
  Likes Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."texto_id" IN (19)
  Dislikes Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "dislikes".* FROM "dislikes" WHERE "dislikes"."texto_id" IN (19)
  SQL (1.3ms)  SELECT "text_medals".*, "t0"."texto_id" AS ar_association_key_name FROM "text_medals" INNER JOIN "text_medals_textos" "t0" ON "text_medals"."id" = "t0"."text_medal_id" WHERE "t0"."texto_id" IN (19)
```

The only inner joins I can see come from a Join table, which makes sense.

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure is a stupid thing, but I can't find it. I will appreciate any insight!

Ninja edit:

Trying with the constraints after the where makes **no** difference apparently.

```
Text.where(:id => params[:id]).includes({usuario: :profile }, :comments, :tags, :likes, :dislikes, :text_medals).first
```

Comment: It's working as expected.  Individual queries will not be made for `comments`, `tags`, etc when you do something like `@text.comments.each do |c| puts c end`; this is where the real performance hit comes into play.

Comment: I thought it took all the resources in a single query, at most two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using `eager_load` instead of `includes`.